# How to make phone vibrate when profile is on vibration mode or never ring when profile is on silent mode and will ring on ringing mode

Tags: java, android, agora.io

As I am developing calling app in Android, I have achieved to play native ringing on call incoming by:

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        ringtone.play();
```

so what I want is to achieve native whole behavior as when we receive a phone call or any other application's call.
(As I am beginner on this site and on android development so please guide me on my mistakes and thank you in advance)

Comment: appreciate your effort thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

try this

RINGER_MODE_NORMAL  This mode is used to set ringing mode in device.
RINGER_MODE_SILENT  This mode is used to set silent mode in device.
RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE This mode is used to set vibration mode in device.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

create an instance of AudioManager class by calling the getSystemService() method with an argument of Context.AUDIO_SERVICE.Once we create an instance of AudioManager class, we can use setRingerMode() method to set the volume or ringing modes of our device based on our requirements.
CODE:

```
AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

by using AudioManager class getRingerMode() method we can easily get the device current ringer mode.

```
AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentMode = aManager.getRingerMode();

if(currentMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL){
    // Do your code
}
```